# Create template for printing reports using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, printing, knockout.js

I have some queries that are made through a form and sent to a Asp.Net MVC action, which returns a JSon containing all the results.

With this result, I set a KnockoutJs Observable Array which fills a table with the items on the array, and handles the pagination.

I want to make this result table "printable".

I'm trying to do this using JS.

What I'm intend to do is implement something like this:

```
function print(data){
    while(!data.IsEmpty())
        DisplayHeader(); //Gets some HTML for the header from the server
        while(!EndOfPage())
            displayRow(data)
        DisplayFooter()    
}
```

Most of these are easy to implement, but my problem is.

How to detect a page break/end of page, so I can display the footer and start a brand new page? (let's assume it will print to a A4 size)

Here's a working example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

This is a Chords & Lyrics brazilian website.

Take a look at this page:
http://www.cifraclub.com.br/guns-n-roses/sweet-child-omine/

and it's printable version:
http://www.cifraclub.com.br/guns-n-roses/sweet-child-omine/imprimir.html

Inspecting the source, it uses some JS to read the original page and then creates the 'printable' version.

Comment: Take it from me, you're better off hassling with a PDF server library than the crocodile tears you'll have when you're done with HTML printing. Although, there is one or two PDF Javascript libraries, but I think they're problematic as well. However, [`page-break` and it's ilk](http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks) are what you're looking for here. You just have infinite more control over printing with a PDF. **EDIT**: Nevermind. You'll need to use some method to figure out the height of the content, the display height of the rows, and use calculations to determine where it goes. PDF, man.

Comment: Jared, take a look at the working example I posted and you will understand what I mean.

About creating the PDF at the server side using iText, I tried but I won't get the same layout and design from the HTML, I'm trying to use a single HTML Template and using it for both display and printing, creating a PDF on the server side I would have to recreate the template for the PDF, imagine that with hundreds of forms...

Comment: I see what you mean. You just have to calculate the height, keeping in mind some browsers allow you to shrink the printable area (I keep Firefox at around 70%). Not familiar with iText, but many like TCPDF allow you to give it HTML, with some tweaks.

Comment: For instance, see the `writeHTML` examples at TCPDF's examples page: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php If you have PHP, it's an option. There are also some extended CSS print properties that I can't remember their names, but I know they're flaky across browsers. HTML just doesn't print well, at least yet.

Comment: I'm not quite sure TCPDF will help. My serverside code is Asp.Net MVC.